# How to export Azure Database using Active Directory authentication and guest account

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I have Azure Subscription with Default Directory with my company's account (myname@mycompany.com) as a guest.

I login to azure portal with this my company's account.

In the SQL Server, I have set Active Directory admin to an AAD group and I'm member of the group.

When I click Export (database) in Azure Portal, I select Active Directory authentication and type my username/password:

[image: export database screenshot]

However I'm getting:

> Failed to export the database: MyDatabase. ErrorCode: 400
>   ErrorMessage: There was an error that occurred during this operation :
>   'Error
>   encountered during the service operation. ; Exception
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.ServiceException:Unable to
>   authenticate request; Inner exception
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:Failed to authenticate the user
>   username@mycompany.com in Active Directory
>   (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword).; Error code 0xCAA20003;
>   state 10; MSIS7068: Access denied.; '

Comment: did you ever get this working? i have the same scenario, my error is different but i want to know if this is at all possible to import/export from a user in the SQL attached AD admin group. 
There was an error that occurred during this operation : '<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Error encountered during the service operation. ; Exception Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.ServiceException:Unable to authenticate request; </string>'

Comment: See the @Tom Sun - MSFT answer;

Comment: so your password was incorrect? after fixed the password issue did the export work?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, it was some time ago, but it could be, that the AAD user was not set as admin in the database. You can set AAD group as database admin, but I'm not sure if it will work with export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failed to authenticate the user username@mycompany.com in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword).; Error code 0xCAA20003; state 10; MSIS7068: Access denied

According to the error information that it indicates that the **user password is not correct**.

Based on my test, it works correctly if you set the Active Directory admin to an AAD group and if you are a member of the group.

[image]